# Definition of an inward-pointing tangent vector for smooth manifolds with corners

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Recall first the definition of an inward-pointing tangent vector for a smooth manifold with boundary.
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary.
If $p \in \partial M$, a vector $v \in T_pM - T_p\partial M$ is said to be *inward-pointing* if for some $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a smooth curve $\gamma: [0,\varepsilon) \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$ (John M. Lee - Introduction to Smooth Manifolds - p.118).

How can we extend this definition to smooth manifolds with corners ?
In particular, how do we define an inward-pointing tangent vector at a corner of the unit square $\square = [0,1]^2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Comment: Does the same definition not work?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Considering for example the example of the square: I am not sure that $\partial \square$ is a smooth manifold, so how do we define $T_{(0,0)}\partial \square$ for example ?

Comment: Well, you need to read about the definitions of manifolds with corners. You can find posts about them on here, too. In the case of the square, a vector is tangent to the boundary at the corner if it is tangent to one of the edges there. The tangent space is no longer a vector subspace.

Comment: I made an edit in my last comment. $T_{(0,0)} \square$ is still a vector space, no ?

Comment: I answered that *explicitly* in my previous comment. No, it is not. You get a subspace only when you are not at a corner point.

Comment: Right... that's why I mentioned the edit: $T_{(0,0)}\square$ is a vector space, but $T_{(0,0)}\partial \square$ is not a subspace of $T_{(0,0)}\square$, is that what you mean ? Otherwise I don't understand why you say "you get a $\textbf{subspace}$ only when you are not at a corner point" (a subspace of which space if $T_{(0,0)}\square$ is not a vector space ?).

Comment: To me the symbol $\square$ denoted the boundary (i.e., the curve). Yes, the tangent space of the two-dimensional object at a corner is a vector space, just as is the case for a manifold with boundary. I'm talking about $\Bbb R^2$ here as the ambient vector space, but of course that's the tangent space of the $2$-dimensional object at any point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130520/discussion-between-deeppinkwater-and-ted-shifrin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a natural way of how to define them. I don't know if this definition is used in literature, but I came up with it and used it in my notes before.

Let $M$ be a manifold (possibly with corners), $p$ a point in $M$, $v$ a member of $T_pM$. We say $v$ is "realizable" iff there exists a smooth path $\gamma:[0,\epsilon[\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$.

Next we define the set of "inward" tangents at $p$ as the topological interior of the set of realizabe tangets at $p$ as a subspace of $T_pM$. Obviously, this is an intrinsic  definition of what it means for a tangent to be inward.

Here is an equivalent definition of inward tangents using coordinates:

Let $M$ be a manifold (possibly with corners), $p$ a point in $M$, $v$ a member of $T_pM$, $\phi:U\rightarrow M$ be a local parameteization around $p$ ($U$ is open subset of $Q^n$). We say $v$ is inward tangent at $p$ iff: for every $i\in[k]$ such that $Pr_i(\phi^{-1}(p))=0$ we have that $Pr_i(D(\phi^{-1})|_pv)>0$.(Where $Pr_i$ is the natural projection to the $i$-th component)

It's an exercise to check that the above definition is  equivalent to the intrinsic definition given at the beginning of my answer and so it is
independent of the choice of the local parameteization $\phi$

Comment: Thank you for this answer !

Comment: @deelppinkwater you are welcome. can you accept the answer (if its acceptable for you) so it gets removed from the unanswered list ?